# Powershell SOAP service - Cannot find an overload for .. and the argument count: "7"

Tags: windows, powershell, soap

I'm writing a windows powershell script (first timer) which needs to call a service running on the same local machine. I have the following code which works for other fetch related methods, but this one gives me the following error:

> Cannot find an overload for "WriteReport" and the argument count: "7".

```
$svc = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://localhost:55810/3/PublicService.svc?singlewsdl"
$svc.WriteReport2(@($body.Id), 'PDF', 0, 0, '', $null, $false)
```

Output of `$svc.WriteReport`:

```
Cannot find an overload for "WriteReport2" and the argument count: "7".
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\App\App_Powershell\App-PS-CheckQueue.ps1:44 char:35
+               $svc.WriteReport2(@($body.Id), 'PDF', 0, 0, '', $null, $false)
+                                   ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest


OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string WriteReport(int[] Ids, Service.ReportFormatType Format, bool
FormatSpecified, System.Nullable[Service.DefaultOrCustomType]
DirectoryDefaultOrCustom, bool DirectoryDefaultOrCustomSpecified, string
Directory, System.Nullable[Service.DefaultOrCustomType]
ReportXslFileDefaultOrCustom, bool ReportXslFileDefaultOrCustomSpecified,
string ReportXslFile)
```

I've [posted the WSDL here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/N4ru4DJE) (a truncated version): http://pastebin.com/N4ru4DJE

I'm quite new to the whole windows environment (powershell, .NET, etc), can someone help me out or point me in the direction?

---

Update:

I tried updating my call to use 6 parameters and match up with the WSLD, but I still get the same error:

> Cannot find an overload for "WriteReport2" and the argument count: "6".
>   $svc.WriteReport2(@($body.taskId), 'PDF', 'PDF', '...\Desktop\Reports', 'Default', '...\Desktop\Reports\Report.xml')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the WSDL that you've just posted:

```
<xs:element name="WriteReport2">
           <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Ids" nillable="true" type="q8:ArrayOfint"                                   xmlns:q8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
                   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReportName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Format" type="tns:ReportFormatType"/>
                   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Directory" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReportXslFileDefaultOrCustom" nillable="true"                                  type="tns:DefaultOrCustomType"/>
                   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReportXslFile" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
```

Your method has 6 arguments: `Id`, `ReportName`, `Format`, `Directory`, `ReportXslFileDefaultOrCustom`, `ReportXslFile`.
You pass 7 arguments:

```
$svc.WriteReport2(@($body.Id), 'PDF', 0, 0, '', $null, $false)
```

Figure out the one you don't need and delete it.

Just to help you out. This is how Powershell sees it:

```
Ids - @($body.Id)
ReportName - 'PDF'
Format - 0
Directory - 0
ReportXslFileDefaultOrCustom - ''
ReportXslFile - $null
? - $false
```

Directory - 0 looks weird to me, but you are the only one who knows what the correct values should be